# Updating a table view from a method in IOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to update a tableview in my app from a method. The table uses the array allShoppingItems as the data source but for some reason I can't seem to add any new objects into the array.. Here is the method. It is located in ShoppingListTableViewController.

```
- (void)addToShoppingList: (FoodItem *) newItem
{
    if (newItem != nil) {

        [self.allShoppingItems addObject:newItem];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

I have tested that the passed object is not nil, nor is tableView.

EDIT:
Here are my numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath methods, also located in ShoppingListTableViewController.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.allShoppingItems count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"shoppingListIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    FoodItem *shoppingItem = [self.allShoppingItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = shoppingItem.itemName;


    return cell;
}
```

The array is initialised in the primary view controller's viewDidLoad method. The following are all in AllItemsTableViewController - The initial view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.allFoodItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    shoppingList = [[ShoppingListTableViewController alloc] init];

    shoppingList.allShoppingItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

and then called in that class' unwind method.

```
- (IBAction)unwindToAllItems:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    AddNewItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    FoodItem *item = source.foodItem;
    if (item != nil) {
        [self.allFoodItems addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    if (item != nil && item.currentNumber<=item.lowLevel) {
        [shoppingList addToShoppingList:item];
    }

}
```

The array is initialised, but empty and no matter what I try, addToShoppingList will not add anything to the array. I print it with `NSLog(@"%@",self.allShoppingItems);` and all it always displays is "()"

Perhaps there is an easier way to achieve this. I just want to be able to add an object to a table view and, if certain conditions are met, add it to a second as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67459/discussion-on-question-by-scott-crater-updating-a-table-view-from-a-method-in-io).

Answer (score -1):

I noticed a glitch in your source code for "CellForRowAtIndexPath" method.

You're correctly reusing a cell. But, you also need to create a new cell if the dequeue process returns nil.

ie: You need to have some code similar to the following:

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"shoppingListIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell==nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

}

Comment: No he doesn't need to do that.  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:is guaranteed to return a cell.